# C# Get last reply in Outlook conversation

Tags: c#, outlook, reply

How to get the last reply in an Outlook conversation? For example, the following code:

```
Outlook.MailItem item = Items.GetLast();
MessageBox.Show(item.Body);
```

will display the entire email, not only the last reply.

Comment: Check the [MailItem.GetConversation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-getconversation-method-outlook) sample code.

Comment: Nah, that won't help. I tried it too. Stil don't get the last reply.

Comment: This is what I wanted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56145308/how-to-get-last-reply-of-a-mailitem-from-outlook-in-c

Comment: Items.GetLast() would anyway give you the last MailItem in the collection. Why were you expecting it would give you the last reply.

Comment: @ShaktiPrakashSingh I wasn't expecting anything because I didn't worked before with this. That's why I asked the question, lol.

Answer (score 0):

The following example shows how to get and display mail items in a conversation.

```
void DemoConversation()
{
   object selectedItem = Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1];
   // For this example, you will work only with 
   //MailItem. Other item types such as
   //MeetingItem and PostItem can participate 
   //in Conversation.
   if (selectedItem is Outlook.MailItem)
   {
      // Cast selectedItem to MailItem.
      Outlook.MailItem mailItem = selectedItem as Outlook.MailItem; 
      // Determine store of mailItem.
      Outlook.Folder folder = mailItem.Parent as Outlook.Folder;
      Outlook.Store store = folder.Store;
      if (store.IsConversationEnabled == true)
      {
         // Obtain a Conversation object.
         Outlook.Conversation conv = mailItem.GetConversation();
         // Check for null Conversation.
         if (conv != null)
         {
            // Obtain Table that contains rows 
            // for each item in Conversation.
            Outlook.Table table = conv.GetTable();
            Debug.WriteLine("Conversation Items Count: " +                   table.GetRowCount().ToString());
            Debug.WriteLine("Conversation Items from Table:");
            while (!table.EndOfTable)
            {
                Outlook.Row nextRow = table.GetNextRow();
                Debug.WriteLine(nextRow["Subject"]
                    + " Modified: "
                    + nextRow["LastModificationTime"]);
            }
            Debug.WriteLine("Conversation Items from Root:");
            // Obtain root items and enumerate Conversation.
            Outlook.SimpleItems simpleItems = conv.GetRootItems();
            foreach (object item in simpleItems)
            {
                // In this example, enumerate only MailItem type.
                // Other types such as PostItem or MeetingItem
                // can appear in Conversation.
                if (item is Outlook.MailItem)
                {
                    Outlook.MailItem mail = item as Outlook.MailItem;
                    Outlook.Folder inFolder = mail.Parent as Outlook.Folder;
                    string msg = mail.Subject 
                        + " in folder " + inFolder.Name;
                    Debug.WriteLine(msg);
                }
                // Call EnumerateConversation 
                // to access child nodes of root items.
                EnumerateConversation(item, conv);
             }
          }
       }
    }
 }

 void EnumerateConversation(object item, Outlook.Conversation conversation)
 {
    Outlook.SimpleItems items = conversation.GetChildren(item);
    if (items.Count > 0)
    {
      foreach (object myItem in items)
      {
        // In this example, enumerate only MailItem type.
        // Other types such as PostItem or MeetingItem
        // can appear in Conversation.
        if (myItem is Outlook.MailItem)
        {
           Outlook.MailItem mailItem = myItem as Outlook.MailItem;
            Outlook.Folder inFolder = mailItem.Parent as Outlook.Folder;
            string msg = mailItem.Subject
                + " in folder " + inFolder.Name;
            Debug.WriteLine(msg);
        }
        // Continue recursion.
        EnumerateConversation(myItem, conversation);
      }
   }
}
```

In the sample code example, we get a selected `MailItem` object and then determine the store of the `MailItem` object by using the `Store` property of the `Folder` object. DemoConversation then checks whether the `IsConversationEnabled` property is true; if it is true, the code example gets `Conversation` object by using the `GetConversation` method. If the `Conversation` object is not a null reference, the example gets the associated `Table` object that contains each item in the conversation by using the `GetTable` method. The example then enumerates each item in the `Table` and calls `EnumerateConversation` on each item to access the child nodes of each item. `EnumerateConversation` takes a `Conversation` object and gets the child nodes by using the `GetChildren(Object)` method. `EnumerateConversation` is called recursively until there are no more child nodes. Each conversation item is then displayed to the user.

Comment: This only displays conversation items, so if you have a conversation with 2 comments, it will display the first one and after that, the second item will be displayed as:

`COMMENT NUMBER #2
_____
From: Someone
Sent: Date
To: Somebody
Subject: RE: COMMENT NUMBER #1

This is the text from first comment.`
I don't need the second part (which is basically the first comment).